# Angular Click Event Issue Error to discover?

Tags: angular, events, onclick

i'm tring to bind click event to search button and submit function but there is an error:

> {hotels: Array(6)} ResultsComponent.html:11 ERROR TypeError:
>   _co.Submit is not a function
>       at Object.eval

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-results',
  templateUrl: './results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./results.component.css']
})
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
  upCase(selectedDate): void {
    this.result = selectedDate;
  }
  upCase2(selectedDate2): void {
    this.result2 = selectedDate2;
  }
  hotels;
  hotel;
  available;
  av; 
  matchedHotels=[];
  result='';
  result2='';
  constructor(private HotelsService: HotelsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.HotelsService.getHotels().subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.hotels=data['hotels'] 
    
     
    });
    
  function Submit(){this.hotels.map((hotel)=>{
    this.available= (hotel.availability)
    this.available.map((av)=>{
      //console.log(av.from);
      if (av.from>=this.result && av.to<=this.result2){
        console.log('true');
        this.matchedHotels.push(hotel);
        console.log(this.matchedHotels)
        //console.log(this.date);
      }
      })
    })
  }

  

}
```

```html
<div class="container justify-content-center mt-2 mb-2  border border-dark rounded mb-0 r">
    <div class="row card card text-white bg-dark ">
        <div class="serch-hotel mx-auto">
          Search Hotel
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 mb-2">
            <div >
                <label>From: </label>
                <app-date-picker></app-date-picker>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 mb-2">
            <div>
                <label>To: </label>
                <app-to-date-picker></app-to-date-picker>  
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>  
</div>
```

[as handleEvent] (ResultsComponent.html:15)

> ```
> at handleEvent (core.js:43993)
> at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
> at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45247)
> at dispatchEvent (core.js:29804)
> ```
>
> Blockquote
>       at core.js:42925
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (platform-browser.js:2668)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390) View_ResultsComponent_0 @ ResultsComponent.html:11 proxyClass @
>   compiler.js:19671 logError @ core.js:45546 handleError @ core.js:6066
>   dispatchEvent @ core.js:29808 (anonymous) @ core.js:42925 (anonymous)
>   @ platform-browser.js:2668 invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
>   onInvokeTask @ core.js:39680 invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:390
>   runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168 invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:465
>   invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1603 globalZoneAwareCallback @
>   zone-evergreen.js:1629 ResultsComponent.html:11 ERROR CONTEXT
>   DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 10, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…},
>   elView: {…}} View_ResultsComponent_0 @ ResultsComponent.html:11
>   proxyClass @ compiler.js:19671 logError @ core.js:45546 handleError @
>   core.js:6071 dispatchEvent @ core.js:29808 (anonymous) @ core.js:42925
>   (anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:2668 invokeTask @
>   zone-evergreen.js:391 onInvokeTask @ core.js:39680 invokeTask @
>   zone-evergreen.js:390 runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168 invokeTask @
>   zone-evergreen.js:465 invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1603
>   globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1629

Comment: did you tried changing the function name to different name

Answer (score 0):

Check your date picker component and see if the function(submit) you are using is defined or imported in the .ts file, also check the function's name.

Comment: Import the component class in order to use the method "Submit" to the component where youre going to use it. Yes you have used the child component to the parent but that doesnt mean it gains access to the methods of the parent's component class. 

Therefore, If you really need to use the Submit method in the parent class(ResultsComponent) you should use the submit method in the parent component, not within its child component(DatePickerComponent). So:

<button (click)="Submit()"> away within the app-results.component.html file

Comment: Can you kindely pleaaase check my project in github

Comment: https://github.com/AsmaaMohmed2018/Search_Hotels/tree/master/src

Comment: please check project link , i want the search button to take the calender values from date picker and uses them in submit function , wheres the calender fires event emitter when changed to send it's value to results component